# D3.js - Updating title for svg path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've a d3 pie chart, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to update some SVG titles which are appended to the individual paths when I update the path values through a selection.

A stripped down version of my code is below.

I've been trying different code snippets, especially in function change(), but haven't found the knack for it yet. I didn't find any good examples already posted, either.

Again, I'm using the path title tags as tooltips and am trying to update their text values as I update the path values.

Any help is so very much appreciated, as I'm on deadline with this project by week's end.

Thanks so much again.

```
var dataset = {
Y2012:  [1000, 2000, 3000],
Y2011:  [3000, 2000, 1000],
//etc.
};

var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(outer_radius - 85)
    .outerRadius(outer_radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select(".svg_container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(dataset.Y2012))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", outer_arc)
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

var tooltips= d3.selectAll("path")
  .append("title")
    .classed("tooltip", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d.value });

d3.selectAll("#select_year").on("change", change);

function change() {
  path = path.data(pie(dataset[this.value])); // update the data
  path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcPathTween);
}

function arcPathTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't update the title text in `function change()`.
Even though your title text is created by a function accessing the data, you have to realize that this function doesn't automagically execute again when you update the data.
This has to be done manually:

```
function change(newYear) {
    path = path.data(pie(dataset[newYear])); // update the data
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcPathTween);
    path.select("title").text(function(d) { return d.value });
}
```

I have also creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rqz6/) illustrating the solution.

If you want to avoid duplication of code (which you should), you could use the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) meaning that you do initialization and update in the same function.

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much! I'm also going to work my way through the general update pattern. Definitely seems the way to go. Thanks again.